# Problem with Select using a Part

Tags: dataset, filtering

I have the following dataset:

```
data = Dataset[{<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3|>, <|"a" -> 3, 
    "b" -> 4, "c" -> 5|>, <|"a" -> "x", "b" -> "y", "c" -> "z"|>}]
```

I can select column 'a' using:

```
Select[data, NumberQ[Slot["a"]] &]
```

Works fine. Then I have a list:

```
l = {"a", "b", "c"};
```

And want to select column 'a' using this list and Part:

```
Select[data, NumberQ[Slot[l[[1]]]] &]
```

Which does not work, and I don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `Function` has the attribute `HoldAll`. That's a bit subtle, since you use `Function` in the quite invisible form of `&`. You can enforce evalution of `l[[1]]` with `With`:

```
With[{slot = l[[1]]},
 Select[data, NumberQ[Slot[slot]] &]
 ]
```

Comment: Great thanks. That is certainly subtle and beyond my daily use. Will need to check this in detail some time.

Comment: You're welcome.